# Why the string.Replace is not working in golang

Tags: string, go, replace

I'm making a program to remove the letters from a string if they exsists. But the expected result will not come. The Program I have tried is below:-

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strings"
)

func main() {
  strValue := "This is a string"
  stringRemove := []string{"a", "an"}
  var removalString string
  for _, wordToRemove := range stringRemove {
      removalString = strings.Replace(strValue, wordToRemove, "", -1)
  }
  fmt.Println(removalString)
  result := strings.Replace(strValue, " ", "", -1)
  result1 := strings.ToLower(result)
  fmt.Println(result1)
}
```

Output:-

```
This is a string
thisisastring
```

If I use the  line `fmt.Println(removalString)` in the for loop then it will print the result:-

output:-

```
This is  string
This is a string
This is a string
thisisastring
```

Expected output:-

```
thisisstring
```

[kheedn li link](https://play.golang.org/p/EhNFVyObcxt)

Answer (score 2):

You always apply the replace operation on the original string `strValue`, so after the loop only the last removable word will be removed (which is not even contained in your example). You should store the result of `strings.Replace()` (you do that), and use this in the next iteration:

```
removalString := strValue
for _, wordToRemove := range stringRemove {
    removalString = strings.Replace(removalString, wordToRemove, "", -1)
}
```

And also use this in your last replacement:

```
result := strings.Replace(removalString, " ", "", -1)
result1 := strings.ToLower(result)
```

Then output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jkL6GVRjqQK)):

```
This is  string
thisisstring
```

Also note that to remove spaces, you can add that to the list of removable words, and you don't need to always create new variables, you can reuse existing ones.

This will also perform the same transformation:

```
s := "This is a string"
words := []string{"a", "an", " "}

for _, word := range words {
    s = strings.Replace(s, word, "", -1)
}

s = strings.ToLower(s)
fmt.Println(s)
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZAMwZqgsaVe).

Comment: if I'm changing the line this `result := strings.Replace(removalString, " ", "-", -1)` then i will include three dashes but I need one dash if there is lot of space. How will I got that. see :- https://play.golang.org/p/ySECjiZ7Iek

Comment: @user10665991 You may replace `"--"` with `"-"`, repeatedly until there is no change (replace). Or you may use regexp for that.

Comment: will you tell me the regular expression? I give it lot of time to solve this :(

Answer (score 0):

this is what youre looking for:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strings"
)

func main() {
  strValue := "This is a string"
  stringRemove := []string{"a", "an"}
  removalString := strValue
  for _, wordToRemove := range stringRemove {
      removalString = strings.Replace(removalString, wordToRemove, "", -1)
  }
  fmt.Println(removalString)
  result := strings.Replace(strValue, " ", "", -1)
  result1 := strings.ToLower(result)
  fmt.Println(result1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`removalString` will be set new value each loop. So `fmt.Println(removalString)` will show the result of last loop.

```
var removalString string
for _, wordToRemove := range stringRemove {
    removalString = strings.Replace(strValue, wordToRemove, "", -1)
}
fmt.Println(removalString)
```

You may do like this

```
strValue := "This is a string"
stringRemove := []string{"a", "an"}
for _, wordToRemove := range stringRemove {
    strValue = strings.Replace(strValue, wordToRemove, "", -1)
}
fmt.Println(strValue)
```